# Can't output more than 3 people in `credits` field with gost-numeric style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, luatex

MWE (3 people):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@book{tag,
  author = {author},
  credits = {One and Two and Three},
  title = {title},
  year = {year},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{file.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: 3 people]

MWE (4 people):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@book{tag,
  author = {author},
  credits = {One and Two and Three and Four},
  title = {title},
  year = {year},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{file.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: 4 people]

Why instead of 4 "people" it now only outputs 1? I didn't find anything about "3" in some `biblatex`/`gost` files (inside `texlive` directory). Why 3?

P.S. I use `lualatex` to make PDF files.

---

**Update**: If I hardcode the same style (`;` sep.):

```latex
  credits = {One ; Two ; Three ; Four},
```

Then the output is what it's should be:
[image: correct 4 people]

But hardcoding things (separator) that can change isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the limiting factor here is biblatex's `maxitems` which defaults to 3; see [biblatex documentation](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

The following tweak to `\usepackage{biblatex}` fixes it:

```latex
\usepackage[style=gost-numeric,maxitems=10]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Yes, now it works perfectly, thank you. I can put this setting in `biblatex.cfg` file (`\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxitems=10}`) (with my other settings) to simplify main latex file.